# Can't access association field. Sequilize + TypeScript. Property '...Info' does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am developing on Node JS + TS + express + sequilize. I am trying to **connect** **device info table** to **device table**. I thing I am doing same as in official documentation:
documentation:

```
class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User, { omit: 'projects' }>, InferCreationAttributes<User, { omit: 'projects' }>> {
  // id can be undefined during creation when using `autoIncrement`
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare name: string;
  declare preferredName: string | null; // for nullable fields

  // timestamps!
  // createdAt can be undefined during creation
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  // updatedAt can be undefined during creation
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;

  // Since TS cannot determine model association at compile time
  // we have to declare them here purely virtually
  // these will not exist until `Model.init` was called.
  declare getProjects: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Project>; // Note the null assertions!
  declare addProject: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Project, number>;
  declare addProjects: HasManyAddAssociationsMixin<Project, number>;
  declare setProjects: HasManySetAssociationsMixin<Project, number>;
  declare removeProject: HasManyRemoveAssociationMixin<Project, number>;
  declare removeProjects: HasManyRemoveAssociationsMixin<Project, number>;
  declare hasProject: HasManyHasAssociationMixin<Project, number>;
  declare hasProjects: HasManyHasAssociationsMixin<Project, number>;
  declare countProjects: HasManyCountAssociationsMixin;
  declare createProject: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<Project, 'ownerId'>;

  // You can also pre-declare possible inclusions, these will only be populated if you
  // actively include a relation.
  declare projects?: NonAttribute<Project[]>; // Note this is optional since it's only populated when explicitly requested in code

  // getters that are not attributes should be tagged using NonAttribute
  // to remove them from the model's Attribute Typings.
  get fullName(): NonAttribute<string> {
    return this.name;
  }

  declare static associations: {
    projects: Association<User, Project>;
  };
}

class Project extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Project>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Project>
> {
  // id can be undefined during creation when using `autoIncrement`
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;

  // foreign keys are automatically added by associations methods (like Project.belongsTo)
  // by branding them using the `ForeignKey` type, `Project.init` will know it does not need to
  // display an error if ownerId is missing.
  declare ownerId: ForeignKey<User['id']>;
  declare name: string;

  // `owner` is an eagerly-loaded association.
  // We tag it as `NonAttribute`
  declare owner?: NonAttribute<User>;

  // createdAt can be undefined during creation
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  // updatedAt can be undefined during creation
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}

...

Project.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'projects'
  }
);

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: false
    },
    preferredName: {
      type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: true
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    tableName: 'users',
    sequelize // passing the `sequelize` instance is required
  }
);

...

User.hasMany(Project, {
  sourceKey: 'id',
  foreignKey: 'ownerId',
  as: 'projects' // this determines the name in `associations`!
});
```

My code:

```
// noinspection JSAnnotator

import sequelize from '../db';
import {
  Association,
  CreationOptional,
  DataTypes,
  ForeignKey,
  HasManyCreateAssociationMixin,
  HasManyGetAssociationsMixin,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  Model,
  NonAttribute,
  Optional
} from 'sequelize';
import Type from './type';
import Brand from './brand';


export class Device extends Model<InferAttributes<Device, { omit: /*[*/'deviceInfo'/*, 'typeId', 'brandId']*/ }>, InferCreationAttributes<Device>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare name: string;
  declare price: number;
  declare rating: number | null;
  declare img: string;
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare getDeviceInfo: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<DeviceInfo>;
  declare addDeviceInfo: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<DeviceInfo, 'deviceId'>;
  declare deviceInfo: NonAttribute<DeviceInfo[]>;
  declare typeId: ForeignKey<Type['id']>

  declare static associations: {
    deviceInfo: Association<Device, DeviceInfo>,
    // typeId: Association<Device, Type>,
    // brandId: Association<Device, Brand>
  }
}

export class DeviceInfo extends Model<InferAttributes<DeviceInfo>, InferCreationAttributes<DeviceInfo>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare title: string;
  declare description: string;
  declare deviceId: ForeignKey<Device['id']>;
  declare device?: NonAttribute<Device>;
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}

DeviceInfo.init({
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    description: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    tableName: 'device_infos',
    sequelize
  });

Device.init({
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
  rating: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0, allowNull: true },
  img: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
}, {
  tableName: 'devices', sequelize
});

...

Device.hasMany(DeviceInfo, {as: 'device_infos', sourceKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'deviceId'});
DeviceInfo.belongsTo(Device, { foreignKey: 'deviceId' });
```

I have an error when I try to access to field deviceInfo in req.body:

```
const deviceController = {
  create: async (req: Request<{}, {}, CreationAttributes<Device>>, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const {name, price, rating, id, typeId, deviceInfo } = req.body;
...
```

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/controllers/deviceController.ts:26:47 - error TS2339: Property 'deviceInfo' does not exist on type 'Optional<InferCreationAttributes<Device, { omit: never; }>, NullishPropertiesOf<InferCreationAttributes<Device, { omit: never; }>>>'. 26 const {name, price, rating, id, typeId, deviceInfo } = req.body;

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `deviceInfo` is marked by `NonAttribute` (because it's association) that's why you don't see it among creation attributes

Comment: Simply define interface something like `DeviceCreationDTO` with `CreationAttributes<Device>` and `deviceInfo: DeviceInfo[]`